# Performance diagnostics in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

We are using asp.net WebAPI,angular,simple.data with oracle provider for .net . so angular connects to WebAPI and retrieve the data with simple.data

We have 2 DC with same configuration . When the application load increases we are seeing increase in response time in one DC alone . To make my point more clear

For the same API
1) DC:1 - Request/hour-3000 Response Time : 496ms
2) DC:2 - Request/hour -700 Response Time : 12 Seconds

We are using perfmon,IIS logs and database logs . We are not able to find the difference why there is performance Hit.

I would like to know If there any other things which can create such behaviour in the application .

The code is both the DCs are identical .

Comment: Turn A off and see what the performance is.  Then turn B off and see what the performance is.  If one is faster than the other, you can better isolated the issue. If they have the same metrics running alone its probably a scalability problem.

Comment: We tried that and we can other DC also becoming slow after few hours

Comment: Are the requests the "same" on both DCs?  Like is there some systematic reason why DC:2 is getting "harder" requests?

Comment: Dc2 actually has less load than 1